# Why is my program become jittery when it's minimized/in background?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, optimization, com

I'm writing a small program that interacts with a CAD package software via its COM API. 
This program is written in VB.net, using WinForm and targeting .NET Framework 4.

Basically what my program does (in order of excecution):

1. Receive and parse incoming serial data
2. Update some GUI controls (textbox/images) based on the parsed serial data
3. Call certain API method with the parsed serial data as arguments, this API method deals with some geometric manipulation of a CAD model (i.e moving or change in dimension)

Those routine is enclosed inside a single `while()` loop and implemented using `BackgroundWorker` so the GUI would remain responsive.

The program works fine when it's currently in foreground (it's not full screen). I can see the geometric changes in the CAD software is running smoothly.

However, as soon as the program minimized and I switch to the CAD software window the geometric changes started to lag/jitter.

Switch the focus back to my program, everything is running buttery smooth again.

**Why exactly is that? could it be when minimized my app get less processor priority?**

How can I fix this?

**Could it be the serial parsing/GUI control updates are sort-of suspended when a program is in the background?** (i.e API calls is blocked before GUI controls can be updated)

Should I extract those GUI update from the main loop?

---

Do tell me if you think more information is required, I will update my question accordingly.

Thanks in advance, I'm fairly new in programming world, so please bear with me. :)

Comment: Did I get it right: your app is doing some IPC (COM Automation?) calls to the CAD app, and the CAD is lagging when your app is in the background?

Comment: No.. the CAD software itself is not lagging. It's fully responsive in fact. The one that's lagging is the automation task being done by my app, or the app itself by extension.

Comment: When you call CAD COM API, do you provide any callback interfaces? Do you handle any events fired by the CAD app inside your app?

Comment: The usual problem is fire-hosing the program with data, forcing a lot of repaints to occur.  When those repaints start to take longer, because more of the window is revealed for example, then a program can get into a state where it stops being able to keep up and starts to stop responding to input and repaint only occasionally.  You must solve it by not exposing the program to a thousand needle-pricks,  batch updates together.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Noseratio no there is no callback interface, basically the CAD program only make certain API calls repeatedly with different argument (e.g incremental move operation with diferent distance).

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but I have tried removed all calls to update its GUI. So all it's doing is doing automation task, no repaint should be done. Still lagging.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially the Windows setting (check system preferences) that has your performance set to boost "active" application (client computers) versus "all applications equally" (servers).

Comment: And if the CAD software actually uses a bit of CPU while it's displaying stuff, especially stuff that's animating, it _will_ use the CPU. If you can run on multiple CPUs/cores the problem may go away.